# Зависание потока при использовании DelayQueue

Tags: java, concurrency

Пытаюсь понять принципы работы DelayQueue и Delay и столкнулась с проблемой. Написала тестовый класс DelayedClass, поместила экземпляр класса в DelayQueue. Попытка исполнить элемент очереди привела к зависанию из-за, как оказалось, единичного запроса метода getDelay(). При первом и единственном запросе метод всегда возвращает положительное значение, после чего остается вечно ждать выполнения условия. Если перед попыткой вызова сделать паузу (через Thread.sleep() или breakpoint'ы), превышающую установленную задержку, то первый же getDelay() вернет отрицательное значение и задача будет исполнена.

Я предполагала, что проблема в некорректно переписанном compareTo(), но упрощение его до return 1, 0 или -1 не дает результата.

В чем может быть проблема? Какой именно принцип работы DelayQueue или Delayed мешает процессу запуститься?

```
class DelayedClass extends Thread implements Delayed {
    Long delay = 1L;
    TimeUnit sourceUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
    Long startTime;

    private void startCountDown() { 
        this.startTime = System.nanoTime() + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(this.delay, this.sourceUnit); 
    }

    DelayedClass() { startCountDown(); }    
    DelayedClass(long newDelay, TimeUnit unit) { 
        this.delay = newDelay; this.sourceUnit = unit; 
        startCountDown();
    }

    @Override
    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit){ 
        return unit.convert(this.startTime - System.nanoTime(), this.sourceUnit); 
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Delayed d){ 
        return Long.class.cast(this.getDelay(this.sourceUnit)).compareTo(d.getDelay(this.sourceUnit));  
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        out.println("Hi, I'm a bit delayed!");
    }
}

public class DelayedElement {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        DelayQueue<DelayedClass> q = new DelayQueue<DelayedClass>();
        q.add(new DelayedClass());
        q.take().start();
    }
}
```

UPD: убрала из описания deadlock, была неправа, зависает один поток.

Comment: Зачем поля класса `DelatedClass` объявлены стаптическими? Вы понимаете, что в итоге все ваши экземпляры этого класса будут иметь одно и тоже значение для этих полей? И с чего вы взяли, что у вас dead-lock?

Comment: @a_gura В статических полях заданы значения по умолчанию, их можно изменить в конструкторе. Да, я понимаю, что лучше было бы вообще избежать статических полей, но я писала "неживой" тестовый пример и потому слегка упростила себе задачу. В любом случае, разве это могло быть причиной описанной ошибки? И если это не deadlock, то что-то из той же сферы, потому что процесс зависает и остается в режиме вечного исполнения. Я еще ученик и извиняюсь, если неправильно употребила термин, но тогда здесь нужен какой-то его синоним.

Comment: @SvetlanaPopova боюсь, конструктор переопределяет как раз статику, а не свойства конкретного экземпляра.

Comment: @Etki Поправила код выше, чтобы более никого не смущать. Статика в данном случае не влияет. И на всякий случай: наличие или отсутствие this в некоторых случаях тоже не решает вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Это не deadlock, потому что у вас "зависание" присходит на блокирующей операции `take`, а не вследствие захвата ресурсов разными потоками. `take` блокируется до тех пор, пока в очереди не будет элемента, для которго `getDelay` вернет неположительное значение. Тоже самое произойдет, если в очереди вообще не будет элементов.

Легко преобразовать ваш пример кода в циклический опрос очереди заменив вызов метода `take` на `peek` или `pool`. Эти методы неблокирующие, соответственно вы можете в этом же цикле вызывать и распечатывать значение, которое возвращает метод `getDelay`. Скорее всего оно будет положительным, либо из очереди будет возвращаться `null`.

Comment: Спасибо, это частично объясняет ситуацию, но пока не решает. Я попробовала добавить в очередь второй элемент с нулевым временем ожидания: он выполнился, но первый так и остался висеть.

Comment: @SvetlanaPopova Так что же вам возвращает getDelay? Можно в самом методе печатать его перед возращением результата.

Comment: getDelay() возвращает уменьшающееся численное значение, которое становится отрицательным по истечении заданного промежутка. Я пробовала выводить его в консоль через цикл, он работает адекватно. Вопрос именно в том, что это цикл, а в моем случае поток выполняет всего один запрос к getDelay() и не следит за изменением.

Comment: @SvetlanaPopova Цикл - это не проблема, это для отладки. Если цикл работает корректно, что и `take`должен рвботать корректно. Во время "зависания" можете также снять thread dump и посмотреть, где же висит ваш поток.

Comment: сняла dump, пишет, что поток ждет AbstractQueuedSynchronizer, который выставил блокировку, как я понимаю, после первого неудачного запроса.

Comment: @SvetlanaPopova `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` используется в реализации всех библиотечных примитивов синхронизации. Конкретно ваш код на каком методе висит?

Comment: конкретно висит на строке q.take().start(). Если я говорю не о том, то,  пожалуйста, уточните вопрос, потому что я уже, кажется, не раз говорила, что он висит именно здесь.

Comment: @SvetlanaPopova О том, все верно. Тот факт, что поток висит на методе `take` доказывает, что очередь либо пуста, либо не содержит элементов с отрицательным значением `getDelay`.

Comment: О том и речь. Очередь очевидно не пуста: я только что добавила элемент и при отслеживании изменений состояний очереди в режиме дебага видно, что на момент зависания она содержит один элемент. getDelay() возвращает положительное значение из-за отсутствия цикла внутри DelayQueue.take(). Почему нет цикла? Я, конечно, могу поместить его прямо внутрь getDelay() но тогда я не очень вижу в нем смысл, ведь куда проще переписать его как getDelay(unit) { unit.sleep(...); return -1; }, не говоря уже о schedule-методах.

Comment: @SvetlanaPopova Простое добавление вывода значений в метод `getDelay` говорит на м о том, что конвертация занчений происходит неверно и значение выводится положительное:
{startTime: 96524506972195, 
currentTime: 96523507278978, 
sourceUnit: SECONDS, 
startTime - currentTime: 999693217, 
return value: 999693217000000000
}

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, о чем вы. Если обернуть getDelay() в цикл и выводить значение на консоль, то оно уменьшается. Пример: задержка 1 сек, вывод значений через 250 млсек, результат: 750393055000000000,
500431453000000000,
250423308000000000,
416559000000000,
-249591120000000000 , на последнем значении цикл обрывается, время жизни цикла адекватно указанной задержке. Если же вы имеете в виду, что В ПЕРВЫЙ раз значение выводится однозначно положительное, то, собственно, как я уже говорила, в том и проблема.

Comment: @SvetlanaPopova Я не делал никаких циклов. Просто добавил вывод значений в сам метод `getDelay`. Если взять ваши 750393055000000000 наносекунд, то это равно 208442.5152778 часам. Ждать придется очень долго.

Comment: но в таком случае, почему у меня цикл работает? Я не знаю, почему число такое большое, но оно уменьшается пропорционально заданному времени. Простой цикл для проверки: `DelayedClass d = new DelayedClass(); Long diff = 1; while (diff >0) { TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(250); diff = d.getDelay(); out.println(diff);}` - цикл закроется через установленное время. Но (в восьмой раз), цикл не выполняется из метода take(). Или вы мне хотите сказать, что он и не должен выполняться? Тогда какой вообще смысл во всем классе Delayed ?

Comment: @SvetlanaPopova Если посмотреть на реализацию `DelayedQuque`, то можно увидеть, то при вызове `take`, если нет кандидатов на возврат из очереди, то основной поток начинает ожидать сигнала на в течении заданного кол-ва наносекунд, которые были возвращены методом `getDelay`. В это время поток заблокирован. Сигнал будет получен либо по прошествии этого времени, либо при изменении состояния очереди (например добавления нового элемента). Т.к. в вашем случае элемент в очереди всего один, то поток блокируется на следующие 208442 часа.

Comment: Спасибо, вы все-таки направили меня на верный путь. Я слышала, что System.nanoTime() может возвращать немного некорректное значение, но не думала, что речь пойдет о десятилетиях. Решила проблему с помощью `new Data().getTime()`

Comment: @SvetlanaPopova Дело не в `System.nanoTime()` а в ошибке конвертации значений. Вы конвертируете `this.startTime - System.nanoTime()` секунд, в наносекунды. В действиетльности вам не нужно конвертировать эту разность, т.к. она, если я не ошибаюсь, уже в наносекундах.

Comment: Действительно, ошибка имела место быть, но не она повлияла на результат. Исправила конвертирование, прогнала несколько раз - результат по-прежнему в десятилетиях. Дело все же в System.nanoTime().

Comment: @SvetlanaPopova Вы можете в это верить, но это точно не так )

Comment: я рада верить всему, что имеет доказательства - тем более, если оно облегчает жизнь! Сейчас проверила эту ошибку на другом компьютере - действительно, работает. но почему прошлая машина отказалась реагировать, ведь я проверила несколько раз? Вроде даже версия одна и та же... Пока что, увы, это только подтверждает ранее прочитанное мной о нестабильности nanoTime().